# Omit double digit enumeration on tables

Tags: tables, numbering, captions

Im currently writing my Bachelor thesis and encountered a small problem. I use document class `scrreprt` but without enumerated chapter (`\chapter*`), and can't manage to alter the caption of tables. They always say `Table 0.1` instead of `Table 1`. I tried using the `caption` package, but did not find a solution to my problem.

Im feeling like there is an easy solution which I'm missing. Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to remove the `chapter.table` numbering style is to use `\counterwithout{table}{chapter}` after having `chngcntr` package loaded.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{Foo starred}

\begin{table}
  \caption{Foo table}
\end{table}

\counterwithout{table}{chapter}


\begin{table}
  \caption{Foo table with no double numbering}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much for the fast reply!

Comment: @user109914: You're welcome. Happy TeXing!