# Numbering of photo and table captions

Tags: numbering, captions

Instead of having captions such as Caption 2.1, Caption 2.2 and so on, I would like to have Caption 1, Caption 2 etc. in my document, e.g. the captions which are not related to the chapters. I am using the following code:

```
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\textwidth]{prizemlje}
    \caption{Osnova prizemlja \cite{5}}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: `\usepackage{chngcntr}` and `\counterwithout{figure}{chapter}`, like in this question (which deals about tables, but it's analogous): http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/319091/omit-double-digit-enumeration-on-tables